# Java ExecutorService invokeAll() interrupting

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I have a fixed thread pool `ExecutorService` of width 10, and a list of 100 `Callable`'s, each waiting for 20 seconds and recording their interrupts.

I'm calling `invokeAll` on that list in a separate thread, and almost immediately interrupting this thread. `ExecutorService` execution is interrupted as expected, but the actual number of interrupts recorded by `Callable`s is far more than expected 10 - around 20-40. Why is that so, if `ExecutorService` can execute no more than 10 threads simultaneously?

Full source: (You may need to run it more that once due to concurrency)

```
@Test
public void interrupt3() throws Exception{
    int callableNum = 100;
    int executorThreadNum = 10;
    final AtomicInteger interruptCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(executorThreadNum);
    final List <Callable <Object>> executeds = new ArrayList <Callable <Object>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < callableNum; ++i) {
        executeds.add(new Waiter(interruptCounter));
    }
    Thread watcher = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                executorService.invokeAll(executeds);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                // NOOP
            }
        }
    });
    watcher.start();
    Thread.sleep(200);
    watcher.interrupt();
    Thread.sleep(200);
    assertEquals(10, interruptCounter.get());
}

// This class just waits for 20 seconds, recording it's interrupts
private class Waiter implements Callable <Object> {
    private AtomicInteger    interruptCounter;

    public Waiter(AtomicInteger interruptCounter){
        this.interruptCounter = interruptCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception{
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            interruptCounter.getAndIncrement();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using WinXP 32-bit, Oracle JRE 1.6.0_27 and JUnit4

Comment: Hmm... converting it into a program with a main method, I'm always getting 10... (Java 7 on Windows)

Comment: Done the same, got 37 (1.6.0_27, Windows XP). Don't have a Java 7 to test, can someone confirm?

Comment: I'll try at work. Maybe it's a Java 6 bug...

Comment: I'm consistently getting 10 here too (1.6.0_24, Windows 7 64-bit).  Your logic looks sound from an initial glance (but then again, this *is* a concurrency question so that might not count for a lot) so I agree that you're expect to see 10 interrupts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with the hypothesis that you should only receive 10 interrupts.

```
Assume the CPU has 1 core.
1. Main thread starts Watcher and sleeps
2. Watcher starts and adds 100 Waiters then blocks
3. Waiter 1-10 start and sleep in sequence
4. Main wakes and interrupts Watcher then sleeps
5. Watcher cancels Waiter 1-5 then is yielded by the OS   (now we have 5 interrupts)
6. Waiter 11-13 start and sleep
7. Watcher cancels Waiter 6-20 then is yielded by the OS   (now we have 13 interrupts)
8. Waiter 14-20 are "started" resulting in a no-op
9. Waiter 21-24 start and sleep
....
```

Essentially, my argument is that there is no guarantee that the Watcher thread will be allowed to cancel all 100 "Waiter" RunnableFuture instances before it has to yield the time slice and allow the ExecutorService's worker threads to start more Waiter tasks.

**Update:** Showing code from `AbstractExecutorService`

```
public <T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
    throws InterruptedException {
    if (tasks == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    List<Future<T>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<T>>(tasks.size());
    boolean done = false;
    try {
        for (Callable<T> t : tasks) {
            RunnableFuture<T> f = newTaskFor(t);
            futures.add(f);
            execute(f);
        }
        for (Future<T> f : futures) {
            if (!f.isDone()) {
                try {
                    f.get(); //If interrupted, this is where the InterruptedException will be thrown from
                } catch (CancellationException ignore) {
                } catch (ExecutionException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
        done = true;
        return futures;
    } finally {
        if (!done)
            for (Future<T> f : futures)
                f.cancel(true); //Specifying "true" is what allows an interrupt to be sent to the ExecutorService's worker threads
    }
}
```

The finally block which contains `f.cancel(true)` is when the interrupt would be propagated to task which is currently running. As you can see, this is a tight loop, but there is no guarantee that the thread executing the loop would be able to iterate through all instances of `Future` in one time slice.

Comment: So you say, that interruption of `invokeAll()` doesn't imply immediate cancellation of all queued tasks before interruption of running ones? For me, it looks like a direct break of least astonishment principle.

Comment: Correct. The worker Threads processing the tasks are distinct from the Thread executing `invokeAll()`. Calling interrupt on one Thread does not imply any other Thread should be interrupted, so I am not at all astonished that you could receive more than 10 interrupts of worker threads on occasion. As I mentioned in the annotated code I posted, an interrupt is only sent to the worker thread processing the task as a virtue of the boolean argument passed to the `Future.cancel` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve same behaviour

```
    ArrayList<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
    executorService.getQueue().drainTo(runnables);
```

Adding this block before interrupt the threadpool.

It will drain all the waiting queue into new list.

So it will interrupt only running threads.

Answer (score 0):

```
PowerMock.mockStatic ( Executors.class );
EasyMock.expect ( Executors.newFixedThreadPool ( 9 ) ).andReturn ( executorService );

Future<MyObject> callableMock = (Future<MyObject>) 
EasyMock.createMock ( Future.class );
EasyMock.expect ( callableMock.get ( EasyMock.anyLong (), EasyMock.isA ( TimeUnit.class ) ) ).andReturn ( ccs ).anyTimes ();

List<Future<MyObject>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<MyObject>> ();
futures.add ( callableMock );
EasyMock.expect ( executorService.invokeAll ( EasyMock.isA ( List.class ) ) ).andReturn ( futures ).anyTimes ();

executorService.shutdown ();
EasyMock.expectLastCall ().anyTimes ();

EasyMock.expect ( mock.getMethodCall ( ) ).andReturn ( result ).anyTimes ();

PowerMock.replayAll ();
EasyMock.replay ( callableMock, executorService, mock );

Assert.assertEquals ( " ", answer.get ( 0 ) );
PowerMock.verifyAll ();
```